# Why does creating a new ViewModel return the same data as the old ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm just learning MVC3 now and this is really confusing me.

I have a `ViewModel` that contains some child ViewModels. Each of the ChildViewModels get rendered with a different Partial View, and when submitting execute a different action on the Controller. All the ChildViewModels should perform some custom validation on their data, and if successful it should move on to the next page. If the validation fails, it should simply return to the `ParentView` and display the errors.

```
[HandleError]
public class MyController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new ParentViewModel();
        return View("ParentView", viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChildViewModelB_Action(ChildViewModelB viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("ChildViewModelB_Page2", viewModel);
        }
        else
        {

            // I'm having trouble returning to the ParentView and
            // simply displaying the ChildViewModel's errors, however
            // discovered that creating a new copy of the VM and displaying 
            // the ParentView again shows the existing data and any errors
            // But why??
            var vm = new ParentViewModel();
            return View("ParentView", vm);
        }
    }
}
```

For example,

- The page loads with 3 options.
- User selects option B and fills out a form.
- Upon submit, the child ViewModel B gets validated and fails.
- Page returns to ParentView, with ChildB all filled out, however ChildB errors are now also showing.

Why does creating a new copy of the `ParentViewModel` display the `ParentView` with the same data as the original `ParentViewModel`?

And is there a different way I should be returning to the `ParentView` after doing server-side validation?

Comment: Why you don't want to show errors in the parent view if the validation fails?

Comment: @Mark I do want to... I just don't know how. The only way I have found to display the errors in the `ParentView` is to create a new ParentViewModel and return the View, however it doesn't make any sense to me as to why that works

Comment: I guess I understand the problem now.. will update the answer.

Comment: Is ChildViewModelB_Page2 is partial view?

Comment: @Mark Yes, its a partial view

Comment: I simply don't understand why you are returning a partial view using View() you should use PartialView() right?

Comment: @Mark I'm really new to MVC... returning a `PartialView` returns just the partial view, without the master form around it. Returning using `View()` returns the full form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the modelstate if you intend to modify values in your POST action

```
else
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    var vm = new ParentViewModel();
    return View("ParentView", vm);
}
```

The reason for that is because Html helper such as TextBoxFor will first look in the modelstate when binding their values and after that in the model. And since the modelstate already contains the POSTed values, that's what's used => the model is ignored. This is by design.

This being said the correct thing to do in your case is to simply redirect to the GET action which already blanks the model and respect the [Redirect-After-Post pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get):

```
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, everything makes much more sense now! :)

Comment: @Rachel you told you want to display the errors in the ParentView.. but I don't think this will display the errors

Comment: @Mark I may have misunderstood your question. The errors are in the PartialView, which is part of the ParentView.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does creating a new copy of the ParentViewModel display the
>   ParentView with the same data as the original ParentViewModel?

Because the values of the fields are retrieved from the POSTed form and not from the model. That makes sense right? We don't want the user to show a form filled with different values from what they submitted.